# Drawable ColorFilter kept through Activity Transitions for the same resource

Tags: android, colorfilter

I have an Activity with some menu items, for which I change the icon colors like this:

```
private void colorMenuItem(MenuItem item) {
  if (item != null) {
    Drawable icon = item.getIcon();
    if (icon != null) {
      icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.some_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }
  }
}
```

The icons are white drawable PNG files from the material icon set. This works as expected and the menu items are colored as desired.

However, when I start another activity which makes use of the same drawable resource which was already colored, but in another view (e.g a FAB instead of the menu), the ColorFilter for this view remains. Why is that?

Shouldn't the FAB load the resource file again and shouldn't it be white (or unchanged)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`However, when I start another activity which makes use of the same drawable resource which was already colored, but in another view (e.g a FAB instead of the menu), the ColorFilter for this view remains. Why is that?`

That is because the drawable or bitmap has been **cached** and therefore the next call to the same drawable id will be the same drawable that was already tinted before.

To fix it is to mutate first the drawable before using it to have another instance of it, to prevent it from being cached.

`Drawable icon = item.getIcon().mutate(); //mutate it to prevent caching`

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but mutating doesn't seem to fix it. I even tried to set it to the menu item again after mutating it, but still no luck.

Comment: @peshkira post your current approach

Comment: 1) I inflate the menu. 2) I get the menu item. 3) I color the menu item as above + your mutate suggestion. 4) The menu item is coloured as expected. 5) I navigate to another activity that has a fab with the same resource as a src icon. 6) the src icon of the fab is also coloured, instead of the normal color. I will try to post screenshots later

Comment: I found that it works, except on one device that I have. It must be some internal bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem before, as I remember filter is being applied every image resource referenced.  You can use

`icon.setColorFilter(null)`

To reset your color filter on resource on your next usage. By this way any filter was applied before this image will be removed.